# How to prove that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^3y^4}{(x-y)^2} = 0?$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I need help calculating this limit. First I tried to plug in $y=mx$, but the limit is still $0$ along those lines. Using polar coordinates is of no help either since the expression is not intependent of θ. I suspect that I have to use the Squeeze Theorem, however I can't find an upper bound.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the limit along the curve $y=x+x^{7/2}$, as $x\to 0^+$, you can get
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^3y^4}{(x-y)^2}
=\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{x^3(x+x^{7/2})^4}{x^7}=\lim_{x \to 0^+}(1+x^{5/2})^4=1.$$
But if take the limit along $y=0$ as $x\to 0$, the limit
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^3y^4}{(x-y)^2}=0,$$
So your limit doesn't exist!

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. I would also like to know your thought proccess to obtain this curve, as I previously tried to use a curve of the form $(x-y)^{2}=x^{3}y^{4}$ but I could not derive an answer of the sort $y=f(x)$

Comment: Ingeneral, if you want to point the limit doesn't exist, you need to take the limit along with two different curves and get two different limits. The domain of function $\frac{x^3y^4}{(x-y)^2}$  is the set  $\{x\ne y\}$, so first I take the limit along the  curve $y=x+x^k $  tangent with $y=x$ at point  $(0,0)$ , and then you will get the value of $k$ as desired!

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The function is not bounded near zero. Indeed, set
$$
x = r \cos \varphi,\quad y = r\sin \varphi
$$
Now for every $\varepsilon > 0$ and $r$ one can find $\varphi$ sufficiently close to $\frac{\pi}{4}$ such that
$$
\left|\frac{r^6 \cos^3\varphi \sin^4\varphi}{(\cos\varphi-\sin\varphi)^2}\right| > \varepsilon 
$$
in other words, for all $r>0$
$$
\lim_{\varphi \to \frac{\pi}{4}} \left|\frac{r^6 \cos^3\varphi \sin^4\varphi}{(\cos\varphi-\sin\varphi)^2}\right| =\infty
$$

Comment: The OP mentions that he tried using polar coordinates.

Comment: $\lim_{\varphi \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \left|\frac{r^6 \cos^3\varphi \sin^4\varphi}{(\cos\varphi-\sin\varphi)^2}\right| = 0$.

Comment: I think, you are right!